# How do you create an sms survey application?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I am a newbie sms application developer. I am looking for pointer on how i could develop an interactive survey based sms application. I want to push questions having check boxes, input boxes, radio buttons etc and receive the inputs back at the server.

Any pointers on how this can be achieved and what app services/technologies can be used for achieving the same would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMS protocol does not support any kind of interactive elements.

You probably want to push in a SMS message containing a link to a mobile site hosting the survey and the interaction happens in the mobile web browser.

Alternatively you can only send 140 character free form questions. However if you send in several questions the users won't answer as typing in many SMS messages is cumbersome.

So your idea of doing it purely on SMS is not feasible. Just create a mobile web site using some CMS with good mobile support and form creation wizards.

E.g http://webandmobile.mfabrik.com/

Disclaimer: I am one of authors

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i was looking at something similar to this http://www.mobiode.com/ there are many others as well, but you see in the demo, they have some sort of a survey published. 

I understand becasue of the character limitation large questions are not possible. Could you let me know what could be the way forward? WAP Push ?

Comment: WAP push does not work on iPhones or Androids as far as know, so that's pretty much destroyes their claim "all phones". Looks like it is ancient product from 2005 not up to modern standards. The way forward is send to http:// link to your query page.

Comment: In fact, in the last sentence mobiode.com tells they just send a http:// link in SMS message

Comment: ahh okay, so in the SMS Link it will point out to a WAP Site where the survey is actually running

Comment: It's not WAP, it's normal HTML website. WAP is dead.

Comment: WAP = different protocol than HTTP

Answer (score 0):

I've been using www.txtlocal.co.uk for quite a while and i'm very satisfied being able to send sms texts through their api. This is commercial service but really worth it's price.

You can use it with all languanges including PHP, ASP, C#.NET, VB.NET, VBA, JAVA, Bulk XML and others.

Simply have a look at code examples: http://www.txtlocal.co.uk/developers/code/

Moreover you can build your own software to process text responses from your clients and even buy your own telephone number.